# Date Difference in Oracle And EDB (Postgres)

Tags: oracle, enterprisedb

In case of Oracle
the Query

```
select SYSDATE - TO_DATE('23-03-1022','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual;
```

is Giving the Output

```
SYSDATE-TO_DATE('23-03-1022','DD-MM-YYYY')
------------------------------------------
                                21715.2233
```

In case of EDB/Postgres it is-

```
select SYSDATE - TO_DATE('23-03-1022','dd-mm-yyyy') as date;
```

```
      date
---------------------
 21715 days 05:23:13
(1 row)
```

How can i get the Same output as oracle in case Of Postgres ?

What does .2233 tells in case of Oracle?

Comment: You fell prey to EDB's marketing claim that their fork is a drop-in replacement for Oracle.

Comment: This Doubt is cleared but have another doubt mentioned here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72487836/oracle-and-postgres-results-different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, `SYSDATE` is a function that returns both date **and** time component. Difference of two `DATE` datatype values returns number of days between them. Therefore, as `SYSDATE` also contains hours, minutes and seconds, you'll almost always get a decimal number as the result (unless you run that piece of code at midnight).

Therefore, I presume that you'd - actually - want to truncate `SYSDATE` which then "removes" time component (sets it to 00:00:00):

```
SQL> select SYSDATE - TO_DATE('30-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual;

SYSDATE-TO_DATE('30-12-1899','DD-MM-YYYY')
------------------------------------------
                                44715.3208

SQL> select trunc(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE('30-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)-TO_DATE('30-12-1899','DD-MM-YYYY')
-------------------------------------------------
                                            44715

SQL>
```

---

As of 0.2279: it is - as I said - number of *days*. To quickly demonstrate it: if you want to get number of hours, you'd multiply it by 24 (the rest by 60 to get minutes, and its rest by 60 again to get seconds):

```
SQL> select 0.2279 * 24 as hours from dual;

     HOURS
----------`enter code here`
    5.4696

SQL> select 0.4696 * 60 as minutes from dual;

   MINUTES
----------
    28.176

SQL> select 0.176 * 60 as seconds from dual;

   SECONDS
----------
     10.56

SQL>
```

Which means that you ran that query *today* at 05:28:10.

Comment: Also can i subtract the 2 dates in postgres without Timestamp?

Comment: Like sv=> select TO_DATE('30-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy');
      to_date
--------------------
 30-DEC-99 00:00:00
(1 row)  Return with timestamp! And in case of oracle it returns wihtout timestamp!

Comment: I can't comment on Postgres, I don't use it.

Comment: Okay no issues! Thanks!

Comment: Can someone Address this doubt as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72487836/oracle-and-postgres-results-different