# Oracle And Postgres results different

Tags: postgresql, oracle, edb

In case of Oracle the Query

```
select SYSDATE - TO_DATE('30-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual;
```

is Giving the Output

```
SYSDATE-TO_DATE('30-12-1899','DD-MM-YYYY')
--------------------------------------------
              44715.4067
```

In case of EDB/Postgres it is-

this same Query gives

```
44715 days 09:46:17
```

which is different Any way to replicate the same O/p in case of Postgres/EDB?

I even Tried the Query

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day from (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('30-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy'))) + EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('30-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy'))::time)*0.00001 as date;
```

but it is giving wrong ans

```
     date
-------------------
 44715.35254000000
(1 row)
```

Any idea how the same O/p can be achieved in EDB/Postgresql?

Comment: Your query doesn't subtract 2 dates, otherwise there wouldn't be any fraction of a day involved.

Comment: Not understood! Cant anything be done?

Comment: When you subtract 2 dates, you should get a the number of days in return. That can never be 44715.4067 A date doesn't have time, so where does this .4067 come from?

Comment: FROM SYSDATE it contains Timestamp!

Comment: And what value is that? How do you know that 44715.4067 is the correct answer?